# Selenium Webdriver C# : Need help accessing the Elements inside iFrame

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am having an iFrame inside an overlayWindow and not able to access the iFrame and its element. I have lots of Menus inside the iFrame and need to test that.

The html code looks like below:

```
<div class="exp overlayContainer" style="">
<div class="overlayBackground"></div>
<div class="overlayWindow" style="position: absolute;">
<div class="overlayWindowInner" style="top: 30px; left: -410px;">
<div id="closetab">
<iframe class="overlayWindowContent" frameborder="0" src="/Templates/frame_loading.html?/my-exp/pers...
```

I am currently using the below selenium code to locate the `iFrame`

```
IWebElement detailFrame = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//iframe[@class='overlayWindowContent']"));
driver.SwitchTo().Frame(detailFrame);
```

but getting the below error message.

**frameElement cannot be converted to `RemoteWebElement`**

Let me know with your comments

Comment: Can you share how the `driver` variable is created? As long as `driver` is a descendent of `RemoteWebDriver`, you should be getting a subclass of `RemoteWebElement` from the `FindElement` method.

Comment: I guess you're running with RemoteWebDriver? If you try with a local driver, does that work at all?

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem and I used `driver.switchTo().frame(0);` and it worked fine for me.